# How to convert column data from GMT timezone to localtime in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have a column "last_status_change_date" which has data in GMT timestamp. I need to convert this data in "GMT-6" ..How can i achieve this ?

```
 select last_status_change_date from bss_calling_card where  card_sn ='030400091074'; 
          last_status_change_date
    -------------------------
     2020-01-03 17:06:51
    (1 row)
```

Result set should be like:

```
last_status_change_date
        -------------------------
         2020-01-03 11:06:51
        (1 row)
```

Comment: What is the datatype of column `last_status_change_date`?

Comment: timestamp(0) without time zone

Answer (score 0):

The fallacy of timestamp with out timezone. Try:

```
select (cast(last_status_change_date as timestamp with time zone) at time zone 'UTC') at time zone '-06:00' last_status_change_date from ...;
```

This takes your timestamp and converts type to timestamp with time zone then informs Postgres which time zone it's currently in and finally indicates the time zone for your desired result.